# Why does ARIMA model values explode for some parameters of "d"

Tags: time-series, arima

I am currently analyzing a financial time series and trying to predict some values with an Arima Model. I found the value of differencing ("d") thanks to the ACF & PACF as well as the ADF statistic-test. So I would use Auto-Arima to find the value of p and q (I fix the value of d) based on the AIC criteria.

However, when I let auto-arima find all the values (including d) it usually comes with the best parameters being (0,4,8) for example. And the issue is that the fitting of the model likely explodes for a certain value.

Based on my research, I understood that the value of "d" rarely goes above 2 but I want to understand the mathematics/science behind that.

Why does the model explode for values of d above 3 ?

Here is a screen of what I mean by "explode":
[image]

I tried to research on my own, I think that it has something to do with the optimization of the parameters that fails each time but yet I am not sure.